# Scifi novel. Colony on the moon, nanotech, sex changing journalist main character

Tags: story-identification, novel, moon, nanotechnology

I read a book years ago about a colony on the moon. Nanotechnology played a huge part in the story. No, it wasn't either of the Ben Bova moon books. In this one, the main character (and almost all the others) has a complete sex change using nanotechnology.  The society in this story doesn't have to work, but people do to keep from getting bored. I believe the main character was a reporter or some sort of journalist. For some reason, I think the author was from Oregon, not sure about that.  I've searched and can't locate this book...

PS- one memorable thing was that one of the secondary characters would have been the queen of England, if they still lived on earth. The feeling I remember having was that the author was commenting on the worthlessness of such status- that true value is in our ability to contribute.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222855/90s-or-earlier-book-with-a-ship-called-heinlein (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 12):

Could this be [Steel Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Beach) by John Varley?

> The "steel beach" in question is Luna, Earth's moon and the most
>   heavily inhabited world in the solar system since the Invaders
>   obliterated human civilization on Earth; the title alludes to humans
>   being figuratively thrown onto the inhospitable moon, paralleling fish
>   that made their way onto land in the evolution of amphibians.
>
> The protagonist, Hildy Johnson, is a newspaper reporter (cf. His Girl
>   Friday; also cf. in reference to Hildy's sex) who finds trouble
>   beneath the surface of the near-utopian society run by the Central
>   Computer. The Central Computer runs every aspect of every person's
>   life: it is the government, court, information source, and friend to
>   every citizen.
>
> Hildy is male at the beginning of the novel. He has become
>   dissatisfied with his life, much like many others on the moon who take
>   part, for example, in destructive activities such as "slash boxing"—a
>   blend of knife fighting and boxing, on which Hildy reports. He has
>   made multiple suicide attempts

For the record, John Varley is from Austin, Texas not Oregon although he did live there briefly.

Comment: The Princess of Wales bit matches *Steel Beach*, as well. And the first line of the novel is not easily forgotten.