# Book about a young girl with something to do with the Moon

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, moon

I remember very few details about the book. I read it in the 1990s. I remember it had a young girl who lives in a clan, maybe? There was something to do with the Moon. I think they had advanced technology. I have a vivid memory of the girl talking about how she learned to clip her nails in a straight line. It is possible this is a well-known book, but I've not had any luck figuring it out.

Comment: Welcome Jason. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for our guidelines. Enjoy the site.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222855/90s-or-earlier-book-with-a-ship-called-heinlein

Answer (score 4):

## Perhaps *Steel Beach*?

Possibly this is John Varley's *[Steel Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Beach)* (1992), which takes place on the Moon after humanity has been forcibly evicted from Earth by aliens that want to protect whales (part of Varley's "Eight Worlds" future history).

Hildy, the protagonist, runs into a secret society of 'Heinleinians', which is developing technology to live unprotected on the Lunar surface. She comes upon them through accidently seeing a young girl streaking naked across a short span of open ground.

I don't remember anything about toenail clippings, but then, it has been almost 30 years since I read the book. Anyway, the timing fits.

[image]